# Saving a file to dynamic path which is a value in Excel cell

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a vba code in PowerPoint which saves the file automatically with the name of an Excel file which is active.

```
 PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "Z:\05_PROJECT\Tanverdi\" & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "ppt"), 1
```

Different people are going to use this macro and they all have different folders that they are using. So i want the path of the folder to be dynamic too. The best solution would be getting the path name from my active Excel cell, so that they can write the path name in an Excel cel and then I can use this cell value as a path.

But how could I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the path is in Sheet1/Cell A1, replace your hard coded path with:

```
PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "ppt"), 1
```

Comment: i want to be able to get the cell value from Worksheet("Vorgaben") while Excel file is active, so i dont want to specify the workbook Name. How can i put this value in to variable and put in the place where you put this.workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1") ?

Comment: Not entirely sure if I follow - when you say "active Excel file" do you mean you have that Excel workbook open (but not embedded in PowerPoint or anything, ie. you have no pointer to that from within your PowerPoint VBA code)? Or do you have a reference to that workbook in your PowerPoint VBA?

Comment: i have an active Excel file before i activate PowerPoint, so i just want to get the cell value as variable like "pathname" and i want to Combine this "pathname" variable with Excel files Name which i already did with Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "ppt"), 1

Comment: Right, so ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vorgaben").Range("A1").Value gives you the A1 cell value on the Vorgaben sheet - it doesn't require the workbook name and you seem to have the ThisWorkbook reference already (same as you do with ThisWorkbook.Name)

Comment: do you mean this ? PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vorgaben").Range("D6").Value & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "ppt"), 1    it doesnt work (This should use the range D6 as Folder Name and & replace part is for getting the Excel file Name)

Comment: What's the error? Also, when you debug it, what does this return: ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Vorgaben").Range("D6").Value & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, "xlsm", "ppt") - is it possible that you have a missing backslash at the end of your path?

Comment: thats the value of the cell D6 :C:\Users\YTANVER\Downloads and the macro saves the file to :C:\Users\YTANVER under file Name Downloadsexcelfilename. It should have saved it to the path C:\Users\YTANVER\Downloads under excelfilename, i must be missing something so Downloads part is not on the path but on the filenamepart